# libXdamage.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to open QfindPro to find out my nas's Ip Address.

```
(base) hutber@hutber:~$ /usr/local/bin/QNAP/QfinderPro/QfinderPro.sh
/usr/local/bin/QNAP/QfinderPro/QfinderPro: error while loading shared libraries: libXdamage.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(base) hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install libxdamage1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxdamage1 is already the newest version (1:1.1.5-2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

I am confused how it can be installed, but not found?

```
(base) hutber@hutber:~$ ldd /usr/local/bin/QNAP/QfinderPro/QfinderPro
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7ed7000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7e96000)
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 (0xf7e68000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xf772d000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xf707a000)
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0xf7037000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Network.so.5 (0xf6ea5000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xf695c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf6939000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf675a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf6655000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6634000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6445000)
    libQt5WebEngine.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5WebEngine.so.5 (0xf6408000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0xf5fe5000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0xf5b51000)
    libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 (0xf1120000)
    libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5WebChannel.so.5 (0xf1100000)
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0xf10ba000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf104d000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf0fdd000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf0fd6000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf0fca000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf0e88000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf0e71000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf0d22000)
    libicui18n.so.54 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libicui18n.so.54 (0xf0aa9000)
    libicuuc.so.54 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libicuuc.so.54 (0xf0901000)
    libicudata.so.54 => /usr/local/lib/QNAP/QfinderPro/libicudata.so.54 (0xef0d6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xef0d0000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7ed9000)
    libsmime3.so => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so (0xef099000)
    libnss3.so => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0xeef0f000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0xeeee1000)
    libplc4.so => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0xeeeda000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0xeee95000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xeee47000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xeed81000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xeed6c000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xeed5f000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xeed57000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xeed4b000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xeed44000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0xeec2e000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => not found
    libXtst.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6 (0xeec26000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xeec17000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xeebea000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0xeeb8c000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0xeeb83000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xeeb06000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0xeeaca000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0xeeabe000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xeea47000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xeea18000)
    libplds4.so => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0xeea13000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xeea09000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0xee9ca000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0xee90e000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xee908000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xee900000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xee8d2000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0xee8af000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0xee7cc000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xee7ad000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xee787000)
```

Comment: The installed location is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1
 so in a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) run ldd /usr/local/bin/QNAP/QfinderPro/QfinderPro to see the libraries it loads and any possible location paths which are wrong.  Add a symbolid link there to the actual location.

Comment: Ah thank you @ubfan1. So I add a symlink from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1` into  `/usr/local/bin/QNAP/QfinderPro/QfinderPro`?

Comment: `libXdamage.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` is what I get now actually. I assume I picked the wrong one then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program needs the 32 bit version of libxdamage (from all the other 32 bit libraries in your ldd output), and cannot use the 64 bit version which is already installed.  Install the 32 bit version with:

```
sudo apt install libxdamage1:i386
```

Comment: I must have removed it without realising!